# Zend 2 Translation setFallbackLocale

Tags: php, internationalization, zend-framework2, locale, translation

Language Files exist for `en_US` and `de_DE`

In my `Module.php` in the `onBootstrap` Method i define:

```
    $oTranslator = $oServiceManager->get('translator');
    $oTranslator->setLocale(\Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']));
    $oTranslator->setFallbackLocale('de_DE');
```

If i enter the page with `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE`: `en-US,en;q=0.9,de-DE;q=0.8,de;q=0.6,pl-PL;q=0.5,pl;q=0.4,pt-PT;q=0.3,pt;q=0.1`

Zend uses the defined fallbackLocale `de_DE` - but why?

If i don't set the fallbackLocale Zend uses the correct `en_US` locale.

I would like to have that Zend uses the given Locale OR, if not found, fallback to `de_DE` - but if the fallbackLocale is defined, he **always** uses the `de_DE` locale

How can i get rid of this behaviour?

**Edit**

The content of my module.config.php for translation is:

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'de_DE',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

**Edit 2**

The Zend 2 Skelleten Application does not have any transaltions for en_US Locale - so all my translation requests of this language leads into empty string return, which will internaly lead to use the default locale.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that `Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` is not returning `en-US` but something else, for example `en`.

If that is the case, the fallback `de_DE` is set.

Are you sure that the value returned is correct? Try to check that first...

---

In [the language header definition](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) there is written:

> Each language-range MAY be given an associated quality value which represents an estimate of the user's preference for the languages specified by that range. The quality value defaults to "q=1".

You set `en` with `q=0.9` and this is not available. 
And then `de-DE` with `q=0.8`.

It might be that since `en` is not available it will use `de-DE` instead.

On the other hand it should set default `q=1` for the `en-US` field. Try to test with something simple for example a single value `en-US`, `de-DE` or `pt-PT`.

Comment: I testet the output of `\Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])` and it returns `en_US` if i come up with the us header - and `de_DE` if i come up with the german header. The language files have the exact same filenames :-/